# Как распечатать результат JS на странице?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Нашел **[отличный js который конвертирует XML в JSON на лету](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/YLJSNv)**

Скрипт быстро выполняет свою задачу но результат виден только в браузере.

Как отобразить результат в самой странице в json формате, чтобы можно было дальше с ним работать?

Спасибо!

```
var xml = (function() {
  /*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Results>
<show>
<showid>2930</showid>
<name>Buffy the Vampire Slayer</name>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Buffy_The_Vampire_Slayer</link>
<country>US</country>
<started>Mar/10/1997</started>
<ended>May/20/2003</ended>
<seasons>7</seasons>
<status>Ended</status>
<runtime>60</runtime>
<classification>Scripted</classification>
<genres><genre>Action</genre><genre>Adventure</genre><genre>Comedy</genre><genre>Drama</genre><genre>Horror/Supernatural</genre><genre>Mystery</genre><genre>Sci-Fi</genre></genres>
<network country="US">UPN</network>
<airtime>20:00</airtime>
<airday>Tuesday</airday>
<akas><aka country="SE">Buffy &amp; vampyrerna</aka><aka country="DE">Buffy - Im Bann der Dämonen</aka><aka country="NO">Buffy - Vampyrenes skrekk</aka><aka country="HU">Buffy a vámpírok réme</aka><aka country="FR">Buffy Contre les Vampires</aka><aka country="IT">Buffy l'Ammazza Vampiri</aka><aka country="PL">Buffy postrach wampirów</aka><aka country="BR">Buffy, a Caça-Vampiros</aka><aka country="PT">Buffy, a Caçadora de Vampiros</aka><aka country="ES">Buffy, Cazavampiros</aka><aka country="HR">Buffy, ubojica vampira</aka><aka country="FI">Buffy, vampyyrintappaja</aka><aka country="EE">Vampiiritapja Buffy</aka><aka country="IS">Vampírubaninn Buffy</aka><aka country="RU">Баффи – истребительница вампиров</aka></akas>
</show>
<show>
<showid>31192</showid>
<name>Buffy the Vampire Slayer - Season Eight: Motion comics</name>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/shows/id-31192</link>
<country>US</country>
<started>Jul/19/2010</started>
<ended>Nov/22/2010</ended>
<seasons>1</seasons>
<status>Canceled/Ended</status>
<runtime>15</runtime>
<classification>Animation</classification>
<genres><genre>Animation General</genre><genre>Action</genre><genre>Adventure</genre><genre>Comedy</genre><genre>Drama</genre><genre>Horror/Supernatural</genre><genre>Sci-Fi</genre></genres>
<network country="US">iTunes</network>
<airtime>12:00</airtime>
<airday>Tuesday</airday>
</show>
<show>
<showid>2931</showid>
<name>Buffy the Animated Series</name>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Buffy_the_Animated_Series</link>
<country>US</country>
<started>2002</started>
<ended></ended>
<seasons>1</seasons>
<status>Pilot Rejected</status>
<runtime>4</runtime>
<classification>Animation</classification>
<genres><genre>Animation General</genre><genre>Action</genre><genre>Adventure</genre><genre>Horror/Supernatural</genre></genres>
<network country="US">FOX</network>
<airtime>12:00</airtime>
<airday>Tuesday</airday>
</show>
</Results>
*/
}).toString().split('\n').slice(2, -2).join('\n').trim();

var oParser = new DOMParser();
var xml = oParser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

  // Create the return object
  var obj = {};

  if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
    // do attributes
    if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
      //obj["attributes"] = {};
      for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
        var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
        //obj["attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        obj['@' + attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
      }
    }
  } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
    obj = xml.nodeValue.trim(); // add trim here
  }

  // do children
  if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
    for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
      var nodeName = item.nodeName;
      //    console.debug('child',nodeName,item)
      if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
        var tmp = xmlToJson(item);
        if (tmp !== "") // if not empty string
          obj[nodeName] = tmp;
      } else {
        if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
          var old = obj[nodeName];
          obj[nodeName] = [];
          obj[nodeName].push(old);
        }
        var tmp = xmlToJson(item);
        if (tmp !== "") // if not empty string
          obj[nodeName].push(tmp);
      }
    }
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj == 'object') {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    if (keys.length == 1 && keys[0] == '#text') return obj['#text'];
    if (keys.length === 0) return null;
  }
  return obj;
}

var obj =xmlToJson(xml);
console.clear();
console.debug(obj);
document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(obj,null,'  ');
```

Перевод объекта JavaScript в строку JSON осуществляется с помощью метода **[JSON.stringify()](https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/javascript-json)**.

Данный метод осуществляет действие обратное методу JSON.parse().

Пример: `var personString = JSON.strigify(person);`

Реализовать на практике не смог.

Как я получал данные из JSON

```
public function getMarket($period, $page)
{
    $items = [];
    $response = (array)@json_decode($this->request('GET', 'https://site.ru/json/my?duration=' . $period . '&page=' . $page)['body'], true);

    foreach ($response as $key => $item) {
        $item['user'] = $this->getUser($item['userId']);
        $items[] = new MyItem($item);
    }

    return $items;
}
```

`https://site.ru/json/my?duration=...` ОТДАЕТ РЕАЛЬНУЮ JSON СТРОКУ В КОД

Answer (score 2):

Просто в HTML добавить любой тег с id="pre" для вывода и все работает

```js
var xml = (function() {
  /*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Results>
<show>
<showid>2930</showid>
<name>Buffy the Vampire Slayer</name>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Buffy_The_Vampire_Slayer</link>
<country>US</country>
<started>Mar/10/1997</started>
<ended>May/20/2003</ended>
<seasons>7</seasons>
<status>Ended</status>
<runtime>60</runtime>
<classification>Scripted</classification>
<genres><genre>Action</genre><genre>Adventure</genre><genre>Comedy</genre><genre>Drama</genre><genre>Horror/Supernatural</genre><genre>Mystery</genre><genre>Sci-Fi</genre></genres>
<network country="US">UPN</network>
<airtime>20:00</airtime>
<airday>Tuesday</airday>
<akas><aka country="SE">Buffy &amp; vampyrerna</aka><aka country="DE">Buffy - Im Bann der Dämonen</aka><aka country="NO">Buffy - Vampyrenes skrekk</aka><aka country="HU">Buffy a vámpírok réme</aka><aka country="FR">Buffy Contre les Vampires</aka><aka country="IT">Buffy l'Ammazza Vampiri</aka><aka country="PL">Buffy postrach wampirów</aka><aka country="BR">Buffy, a Caça-Vampiros</aka><aka country="PT">Buffy, a Caçadora de Vampiros</aka><aka country="ES">Buffy, Cazavampiros</aka><aka country="HR">Buffy, ubojica vampira</aka><aka country="FI">Buffy, vampyyrintappaja</aka><aka country="EE">Vampiiritapja Buffy</aka><aka country="IS">Vampírubaninn Buffy</aka><aka country="RU">Баффи – истребительница вампиров</aka></akas>
</show>
<show>
<showid>31192</showid>
<name>Buffy the Vampire Slayer - Season Eight: Motion comics</name>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/shows/id-31192</link>
<country>US</country>
<started>Jul/19/2010</started>
<ended>Nov/22/2010</ended>
<seasons>1</seasons>
<status>Canceled/Ended</status>
<runtime>15</runtime>
<classification>Animation</classification>
<genres><genre>Animation General</genre><genre>Action</genre><genre>Adventure</genre><genre>Comedy</genre><genre>Drama</genre><genre>Horror/Supernatural</genre><genre>Sci-Fi</genre></genres>
<network country="US">iTunes</network>
<airtime>12:00</airtime>
<airday>Tuesday</airday>
</show>
<show>
<showid>2931</showid>
<name>Buffy the Animated Series</name>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Buffy_the_Animated_Series</link>
<country>US</country>
<started>2002</started>
<ended></ended>
<seasons>1</seasons>
<status>Pilot Rejected</status>
<runtime>4</runtime>
<classification>Animation</classification>
<genres><genre>Animation General</genre><genre>Action</genre><genre>Adventure</genre><genre>Horror/Supernatural</genre></genres>
<network country="US">FOX</network>
<airtime>12:00</airtime>
<airday>Tuesday</airday>
</show>
</Results>
*/
}).toString().split('\n').slice(2, -2).join('\n').trim();

var oParser = new DOMParser();
var xml = oParser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

  // Create the return object
  var obj = {};

  if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
    // do attributes
    if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
      //obj["attributes"] = {};
      for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
        var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
        //obj["attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        obj['@' + attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
      }
    }
  } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
    obj = xml.nodeValue.trim(); // add trim here
  }

  // do children
  if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
    for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
      var nodeName = item.nodeName;
      //    console.debug('child',nodeName,item)
      if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
        var tmp = xmlToJson(item);
        if (tmp !== "") // if not empty string
          obj[nodeName] = tmp;
      } else {
        if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
          var old = obj[nodeName];
          obj[nodeName] = [];
          obj[nodeName].push(old);
        }
        var tmp = xmlToJson(item);
        if (tmp !== "") // if not empty string
          obj[nodeName].push(tmp);
      }
    }
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj == 'object') {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    if (keys.length == 1 && keys[0] == '#text') return obj['#text'];
    if (keys.length === 0) return null;
  }
  return obj;
}

var obj =xmlToJson(xml);
console.clear();
console.debug(obj);
document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(obj,null,'  ');
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Nsk, спасибо! Да работает, но я не понимаю, как дальше работать с этим результатом, он же в index.html Как мне с помощью php получать нужные параметры и заносить их в базу данных? Раньше я с помощью php обращался к странице с JSON строкой реально пропечатанной в коде, здесь же ее нет. https://i.gyazo.com/702c51138e689b0f0c2a9f5cfb1520d0.png

Comment: Добавил свой пример в вопрос.